# Zebra Bluetooth printer left margin command on line break

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I am using zebra printer to print some data (data sent from android mobile html page). It is working fine but I need some margin from left side when line breaks. I am using `! U1 SETLP 5 0 20\n ! U1 SETBOLD 0\n` +data. command.

Comment: namely, that the sending through html page?
if this line can immediately left side of the line you need to add a space

Comment: it will be better if margin from left side and right side are equal either line break or starting of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found perfect solution for this.

```
! U1 LMARGIN 15
```

[Click on the link and read page no. 33](http://www.maxatec-europe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/CPCL_Commands_Manual_1.1.pdf)